# Why is Object.assign correctly infered, while Object.create isn't?

Tags: typescript

```
interface Example {
  a: string;
}

const notExample = { a: 5 }; // This object doesn't satisfy the interface Example

const errors: Example = Object.assign({}, notExample); // Type '{ a: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Example'.

const works: Example = Object.create(notExample); // Working correctly and it shouldn't
```

Why doesn't `Object.create` return `T` for `typeof Argument`, instead it returns `any`?

`Object.assign` returns `T & U` for two passed arguments, as one would expect.

Comment: Take a look at [this github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3865)

Comment: Could it be because `works` does *not* have any properties itself? `Object.create` will create a new object with the argument as its prototype, so `works.hasOwnProperty("a") //false`. Not sure if TS makes any decisions based on that. Although in that case it doesn't have an `a` property...

Comment: @VLAZ Sure, but `works.a` will still be a number and not a string. It will look up the proto chain, so I don't think it should work.